# Validity of Huffman encoding

Tags: encoding, huffman-code

The encoding is
A : 0
B : 11
C : 100
D : 101

The sure thing I can say from this is A has the highest probability, followed by B and then either of C and D (since prob(C) + prob(D) < prob(B)).

However, considering A > B > C > D in terms of probability values, or A > B > D > C, I don't get the above encoding as:

```
--0--A
|
--1----1---B       <- Should actually be zero as left branch should always be zero
    |
    ---0-----0--C  <- First zero should be 1, but it's not.
          |
          ---1--D
```

It does satisfy the prefix constraint, but is there a counter-example that shows that the above encoding does in fact work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing that says which branch should be zero and which should be one. You can come up with many encodings of the same set of symbol lengths. (Look up "canonical Huffman code" for a convention to resolve this.) The encoding "works" because it is a prefix code, and it will compress the symbols well if their probabilities are close to 1/2, 1/4, 1/8, and 1/8.